# zkoss textbox constraint="/\p{InCyrillic}*/"

Tags: unicode, textbox, constraints, zk, zul

Why it doesnt work whith regexp \p{InCyrillic}?
I tried \p{L} but it doesn`t work too.
My code in zul:

```
textbox  id="box" hflex="1" constraint="/\p{InCyrillic}*/"
```

Comment: What constraints you want to place can you briefly explain

Comment: Only Cyrillic letters.

Comment: I do not think it will work like this you have to give some regular expression here because if you will write English inside constraints it does not mean it will take English letters.

Comment: If you do not know what mean \p{InCyrillic} or \p{IsCyrillic}

Comment: Try this http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented own Constraint:

```
package com.upc.webcallcentr4zk.controller.constraints;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.WrongValueException;
import org.zkoss.zul.Constraint;
import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;

public class PatterenCostraints implements Constraint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4052163775381888061L;
    private Pattern pattern;

    public PatterenCostraints(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Component comp, Object value) throws WrongValueException {
        if (comp instanceof Textbox) {
            String enteredValue = (String) value;
            if (enteredValue.isEmpty()) {
                throw new WrongValueException(comp, "Bla bla bla!");
            } else if (!pattern.matcher(enteredValue).matches()) {
                throw new WrongValueException(comp, "Bla bla bla!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that:

```
keywordBox.setConstraint(new PatterenCostraints("^(\\p{IsCyrillic}*)$"));
```